# Bus tracking system using google maps distance matrix api

Tags: google-maps, real-time

I am trying to create a real time bus tracking application using Google distance matrix service to provide estimation time of arrival when the user clicks on the bus icon. To do this, I have created a function dorefresh which grabs latlong value every 10 seconds from a file and send it to another function to be displayed on the map.

The problem I am facing currently is that the function calculatedistance() is inside the loop, thus the function calculatedistance() is called automatically and it displays outside of the map. I would like the system to be able to only display the estimated time only on the infowindow when user selects the bus icon. Also, the outputdiv is located in the body of the code. Kindly assist. Thank you very much

Below is my codes for bus1 and dorefresh

```
  function bus1(b1_lat, b1_lon)
{
    if(b1_lat != '')
    {
        var b1_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(b1_lat, b1_lon);

        if(!b1_marker)
        {
            b1_marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: b1_latlng, 
                map: map, 
                title:"BUS 1",
                icon: busmarker
            });

            var b1_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            {
                content: outputDiv
            });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(b1_marker, 'click', function()
            {

                b1_infowindow.open(map,b1_marker);
            });
        }

        else
        {
            calculateDistances(b1_lat, b1_lon);
            b1_marker.setPosition(b1_latlng);

        }

    }       

}

    doRefresh();
function doRefresh() 
{
    var xhr; 
    try 
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) 
    {
        xhr = false;
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function() 
    { 
        if (xhr.readyState  == 4) 
        {
            if (xhr.status  == 200) 
            {
                b1_dte = xhr.responseText.split('_')[0];
                b1_lat = xhr.responseText.split('_')[1];
                b1_lon = xhr.responseText.split('_')[2];
                if (b1_dte && b1_lat && b1_lon) 
                {
                    bus1(b1_lat, b1_lon);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", "http://203.80.17.205/~shankara/final/i-am-here-position?" + Math.random(),  true); 
    xhr.send(null);
    setTimeout('doRefresh()', 3000);
}
    <body>
<div id="panel">
    <input id="route1" type="checkbox" onClick="toggleLayer(flightPath,'route1')" /> Route 1

</div>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 700px; height: 600px"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post an example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: hi @not_a_bot the problem is highlighted in yellow on the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_X_DVZcd4g-ZGtQakJ0WU9DUFU/view?usp=sharing.. This value automatically appear hear onload, while it suppose to be displayed when the user clicks on the bus such as: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_X_DVZcd4g-SjV4QndoUVdXelk/view?usp=sharing..

Comment: I would recommend moving the code for your infowindow and onclick listener out of your bus1 function. Also, it looks like your infowindow is in a div on top of the map as opposed to being in the map. Can you try doing it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/yu3BN/ ?